# OCR with android app

Tags: android, ocr

I want to create an app where people can take a photo of 
any text and the app recognizes the text, copies it and 
puts it into an editable area.

The language of the text shouldnt matter. I just want to 
automatically recognize the characters. A later feature 
could be to provide text translations.

Is there any ocr library for android apps?
As i remember google wanted to provide an api for ocr (last information about it i got in the year 2011). As it seems there is no api for it yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you may want to look at Tesseract OCR Libraries. They are free and open sourced. https://code.google.com/p/tesseract-android-tools/

Answer (score 3):

use tesseract .. refer here for the base library https://github.com/rmtheis/tess-two ..